# How to create and manage a dynamic page based on user generated content

Tags: php, javascript, drupal

I'm trying to create a website that will take data from some file as input to a javascript page that will then do some data crunching and spit out some html. Additionally, I want the website to allow users to upload their own data to then be displayed. I'm imagining something like where the top center of the page has the results of the javascript, and below is a list of uploads and clicking on one will update the top display with new data from that upload.

I obviously don't want to reinvent the wheel and roll my own user authentication and content management system, so I was looking at drupal. Is there some way to extend drupal to do this (or a module that already does)? Or is there a better way entirely that I'm not aware of? Thanks.

Comment: So just to simplify your request- you want a content area whose content is loaded dynamically after the user clicks one of the links, each of which is a reference to something a user uploaded? I'm not sure I ever have seen a system like that, honestly. Keep asking, but if you don't get a good answer, you may have to "reinvent the wheel" on this one. I suggest using jQuery or similar to simplify the AJAX request for updating the content area, then use a single MySQL table to manage the data on the back-end.

Comment: Exactly. I know that drupal can do file uploads with CCK and filefield. I'm really just missing a way to make a permanent js content area at the top of the page and a way to have the links call a js function with the upload data as input. My biggest concern is reimplementing user authentication and file uploads securely, a problem which frameworks like drupal have already solved.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a framework for this, but look into jQuery templating. Other javascript libraries also offer something similar. You might also want to look into the Cappuccino framework.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a very specific JavaScript use case. It is necessary for all these things to take place on the client (i.e. browser) side with JavaScript? Can it not be done on server side? There are thousands of modules in Drupal and some of them might be able to fully/partially meet your requirements .

I'd suggest you buy a ebook/book version of the excellent https://www.packtpub.com/drupal-6-javascript-and-jquery/book by matt butcher. After reading this book you should be able to get a fair idea of the direction you need to head in.

Comment: I'm actually looking for a server side solution. I just want to be able to have a permanent area in the middle of the page. A pretty close example I can think of is mapofstrange.com. They have a google maps section of their page (js) and a changing list of data on the side that affects the js part when you click on it. The biggest difference is I want to include user-uploaded content.